# Making web service call using apache camel

Tags: apache-camel

I would like to call a third party webservice using Apache Camel. The method is neither REST nor SOAP. It is via XML over HTTPS. How can I make this call? Is it possible to do it via camel configuration file where I already have defined multiple routes?

Comment: XML over HTTPs can be both RESTful or SOAP. Camel can do both, but you need to describe the endpoint behaviour.

Comment: Hi, Could you let me know how to configure the endpoint in case it is a HTTPS? Through this call, I would be accessing the client's API and fetching some data via URL.

Comment: http://camel.apache.org/http.html